# Can you dereference a temporary array?

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer, c++20, temporary-objects

Consider the following code:

```cpp
void foo() {
    int arr[1];
    *arr; // OK

    using T = int[1];
    *T{}; // OK for Clang and MSVC
          // GCC error: taking address of temporary array
}
```

*See [live code at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/r3WzcdMq8)*.

My intuition is that `*T{}` should result in array-to-pointer conversion, and the indirection is well-formed.
However, I'm not entirely sure about this.

Is GCC right, or is this a bug? Is it intentional, to prevent developers from making mistakes? After all, you don't usually dereference arrays. Is this documented anywhere?

| Disclaimer |
| --- |
| [CWG Issue 2548](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2548) has confirmed that **"indirection through an array prvalue is also not valid today"**. The answer by @StoryTeller is wrong, and misinterprets the meaning of [destination type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.general#def:destination_type) by assuming that this also applies to `*T{}`, but this expression is not initialization of a pointer. |

*More discussion at editorial issue [EDIT 6555](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/6555)*

Comment: Your compiler explorer link do not show error message :( (looks like bug in compiler explorer). Here is more handy link: https://godbolt.org/z/4Mar7dMEq

Comment: `(T{})[0];` Works. Why gcc complains about taking an address? Is `*` operator taking address? Odd.

Comment: @KamilCuk that could be simplified to `T{}[0]`. I guess it's the fact that it's an alias for `*(T{} + 0)` so the indirection isn't "directly" on the array.

Comment: `*T{}` is mistaken by compiler for an empty case  of compound literal due MVP-like behaviour, which is a C construct but not legal C++. Compound literals may exist as an extension in C++ compiler, that's what Clang and MSVC might be doing or they properly recognise it as not such.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie a compound literal needs parentheses. `T{}` is just a type name followed by a braced-init-list. It's perfectly legal for `T = int`, and all compilers treat it the same.

Comment: @JanSchultke yeah, it does in C, it's the only cast there! It might be a bug in language model. I sadly didn't save a wild example of similar error I got some year ago with GCC, where it treated T{} as a cast, similar to (T), with similar error within a template. To think about it, T was an array in that case...

Comment: `int* a = T{0};` and  `int* a = (T){0};` for GCC both produce same error message about temporal address, if T is an array (ok to bind to `T&&`). Clang shows correct message abous assignment mismatch.   is an error.  I guess, it's an edge case bug. For GCC, `T{}` and `T{0}` are same thing for an array, seems `T` and `(T)` too.

Comment: GCC issue: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC is right because indirection can only be applied to pointers. [[expr.unary.op]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.unary.op#1):

> The unary `*` operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied **shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type** and the result [...]

*Note: [CWG 1642](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1642) and [EDIT 3945](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/3945) makes indirection apply to a **prvalue** operand.*

`*arr` is OK because `arr` is an lvalue, and [[basic.lval]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lval#6):

> Whenever a glvalue appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer standard conversions are applied to convert the expression to a prvalue.

Array-to-pointer conversion ([[conv.array]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.array)) is applied  to`arr`.

`T{}` is already a prvalue (of array type), and there is no wording which necessitates array-to-pointer conversion here, so `*T{}` is not OK.

Comment: Does the same thing happen to `[]`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [expr.sub] says «One of the expressions shall be a glvalue of type “array of `T`”», so we can say that [basic.lval]/7 apply. OTOH, I agree it is unclear why we chose this instead of pointing at [expr.sub] saying «or a prvalue of type “pointer to `T`”» and claiming that prvalue of array type does not fit. I think [expr.sub] is the only case when operator accepts both glvalues and prvalues of object type. I'm periodically thinking to file an (editorial?) issue for many years, but still didn't for some reason

Comment: @HolyBlackCat _it is unclear why we chose this_ Well, prolly from the intent. In C++14, before «Guaranteed copy elision through simplified value categories», array prvalues denoted temporary objects and [expr.sub] applied to all expressions of array type. And «Guaranteed copy elision» did not intend to break this.

Comment: What about `using T = int(&&)[1]; *T{};`? GCC doesn't seem to have an issue with that.

Comment: @303 https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1521

Comment: Or `using T = int(*)[1]; **T{};` for that matter? As GCC accepts this as well. While the original example might be illegal for the reasons you've laid out, it seems to me that GCC is simply showing some buggy behavior in this particular scenario.

Comment: @303 _As GCC accepts this as well_ And what should surprise here? `T{}` is a prvalue of pointer type, [expr.unary.op]/1 is happy about it. (`*T{}` is UB/CWG232, because this is an indirection through a null ptr. But `*T{}` is an lvalue, and interaction of `*` applied to an lvalue is covered in the answer)

Answer (score 1):

It seems well-defined to me, and Clang and MSVC do it as required.

> **[expr.unary.op]** (emphasis mine)
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.unary.op#1) The unary `*` operator performs indirection: **the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type** and the result is an lvalue referring to the object or function to which the expression points.

Then we have this sentence that tells us when and where a standard conversion sequence can be applied:

> **[conv.general]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.general#1) Standard conversions are implicit conversions with built-in meaning. [conv] enumerates the full set of such conversions. A *standard conversion sequence* is a sequence of standard conversions in the following order:
>
> - Zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and function-to-pointer conversion.
>
> **...**
>
> A standard conversion sequence will be applied to an expression if necessary to convert it to a required destination type.

Which tells us that a standard conversion sequence can be applied to convert an operand to a type required by an expression. That's how it works with `*arr`, and so we need only check if the array-to-pointer conversion can be applied to our prvalue array.

> **[conv.array]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/conv.array#1) An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to T”. The temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied. The result is a pointer to the first element of the array.

And it can, as the standard even explicitly requires a temporary array to materialize and for the pointer to point at its first element. All in all, GCC reject valid code, so one can say it has a bug.

Comment: I can't comment on whether or not it's a known bug that's left in intentionally or not. I don't recall ever seeing such an example in the wild, so I wouldn't fault the GCC devs either way.

Comment: I thought this answer is correct at first glance. However, contrary to intuition, implicit conversions don't just take place whenever possible; It needs to be explicitly stated. This is why e.g. [expr.mul] specifies that multiplication is defined for arithmetic types or unscoped enumerations, even though unscoped enumerations are convertible to arithmetic types. It is nowhere stated that the indirection of an array is a context in which explicit conversion is required, so it doesn't apply here. GCC is right.

Comment: @JanSchultke - It was far from intuition. "*If necessary*" over there leaves the whole subject far from shut closed. Could be a defect in itself, or intentionally left so they can flip flop their opinions on a whim. Either way, I don't subscribe to the view you seem sold on, so I'll be keeping my answer. Content rating will do its thing, and it might even lead to a clear enough change in the standard. If and when such a day comes, I'll delete it then.

Comment: The subject is not shut and closed. You're citing a paragraph that is the definition of *implicit conversion*. Context is important. The standard explicitly states when conversions are applied, and to which operands. For example, [expr.ass] states explicitly that the right operand is converted to the type of the left operand. If you think that [conv.general] is a blanque cheque for implicit conversions everywhere, why do you think the standard states explicitly when these conversions happen?

Comment: And appealing to content rating is a very dangerous thing when language lawyering. If I knew that my answer was incorrect and misleading, I would correct or delete it. I'm not saying you think that yet, but you should seriously reconsider whether your extremely generous interpretation of [conv.general] is appropriate; especially since you have no CWG issues or anything else to explain what the likely intent is.

Comment: @JanSchultke - Because it is written by different people working separately over 30 years now. Someone coming along overly cautiously does not erase previous intent in normative text.

Comment: The standard is constantly refined and reviewed. The working draft is available on GitHub and there are many eyes on it. If numerous sections (especially ones as commonly viewed as [expr] had this pointless redundant wording that gets obsoleted by [conv.general]), this likely would have been fixed now. Instead of making grand and broad claims about "this was written over a long time", you should open an issue in the `cplusplus/draft` repo and tell these people that the wording is redundant. See how it goes.

Comment: Appeal to rating is "dangerous"? What do you think "balloting" is for proposal admission?

Comment: Ah, you are of the opinion the committee is 100% rational. Figures, it explains much.

Comment: I'm saying that a lot of people have worked on the wording and if [conv.general] seemingly obsoletes numerous paragraphs, then either this is a significant defect in the language that no one has spotted, or you're misinterpreting it.

Comment: Appeal to popularity makes zero sense because the audience of this website at large isn't committee members. The people voting on your post aren't CWG members, they're internet users. They could be wrong on language technicalities, even if your post is more agreeable on an intuitive level to internet users.

Comment: @JanSchultke - They only recently fixed a defect affecting the very definition of `std::byte`, so yeah I am going with they miss or ignore it. Feel free to downvote and carry on with your day. I spilled enough energy down this rathole, peace out.

Comment: You're just coping at this point and pointing out that some defect elsewhere justifies a completely unrelated wording issue in a different area. There is no logic behind this; you're just making broad claims that attack the quality of the standard in general, and could be used to make whichever interpretation your heart desires correct, regardless of what the wording really is, or what the intent behind it is.

Comment: _A standard conversion sequence will be applied to an expression if necessary to convert it to a required **destination type**_ This seems to apply only to initialization, because «The [destination type](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.general#def:destination_type) is the type of the object or reference being initialized». Looks like it should be read together with https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.general#16.9

Comment: EWG decided to not support this nonsense https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/1633#issuecomment-1799749584